# setState in a Context.Provider doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to update the value of a variable with setState and when it is used it is with the initial value, I use this variable with useContext globally.
This is the Provider, I think they are well structured since I have a similar one and if it works.

```js
const BusquedaProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [busqueda, setBusqueda] = useState(initialBusqueda);
  const [vuelosArray, setVuelos] = useState(initialVuelos);
  const [vueloCompra, setVueloCompra] = useState(initialVueloCompra);

  const editBusqueda = (data) => {
    setBusqueda(data);
  };
  const editVuelos = (data) => {
    setVuelos(data);
  };
  const editVueloCompra = (data) => {
    setVueloCompra(data);
  };

  const data = {
    busqueda,
    editBusqueda,
    vuelosArray,
    editVuelos,
    editVueloCompra,
    vueloCompra,
  };
  return (
    <BusquedaContext.Provider value={data}>{children}</BusquedaContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I use this Provider in this code (in another file), for example editBusqueda(info) It should update the search value but at the time of printing it does not work. The same when

```js
const { busqueda, editBusqueda, vuelosArray, editVuelos } =
  useContext(BusquedaContext);
let location = useLocation();
const info = location.state.info;

editBusqueda(info);
console.log(busqueda);

const originCities = location.state.originCities;
const destinationCities = location.state.destinationCities;

useEffect(() => {
  getVuelos();
  Vuelos();
}, []);

const getVuelos = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(
    `${
      URI_vuelos +
      "codvuelo/" +
      info.originCity +
      "/" +
      info.destinationCity +
      "/" +
      info.dateIn +
      "/" +
      info.dateOut
    }`
  );
  editVuelos(res.data);
};
getVuelos();
```

I expect the value of the variables to change immediately after using setState.

Comment: Is there any error in the console? Are you wrapping your app in authState?

Comment: You should not update state directly in the body of the component. Use useEffect for this. You can not change the state value immediately, it has to finish the current render and after that is should re-render to give you the value that is being set

Comment: how can i use the useEffect to avoid the error?

Comment: Using setState in the body is recommended compared to useEffect (https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#adjusting-some-state-when-a-prop-changes), but a) it depends on the context if that's the best solution and b) it can trigger a lot if you're not careful. You _do_ have some issues there, like `getVuelos` causing a loop potentially. The specific problem with the value here is that `setState` is async, the value changes _for next render_ only. If you do `setSomeVar('x'); console.log(someVar);` you're always going to see the previous value.

Comment: @JakubKotrs you can help me? I am junior developer and I don'r know and I don't understand how to avoid

Comment: Small steps here. "I expect the value of the variables to change immediately after using setState." - this is simply a wrong expectation. React doesn't work like that at all. This is the first thing you need to solve. You need top-down flow, from parent to child. Data needs to flow this way. If you have `const info = location.state.info` why do you need to propagate it back up? Can you use the `info` directly?